# NullPointerException in Appium Java Client

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am getting a `NullPointerException` while trying to setup a simple AndroidDriver.

The required code is below -

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestAutomation {
    protected AndroidDriver<MobileElement>  driver;

    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        URL u = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(u, capabilities);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestAutomation object = new TestAutomation();
        System.out.println(object);
        object.setup();
    }
}
```

The Appium Java client version is 6.1.0.

Verified that Appium server is running on localhost at port 4723.

Is there something I am missing?

The Exception I am getting is shown below -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.getCapabilities(AndroidDriver.java:209)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:669)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:93)
>         at TestAutomation.setup(TestAutomation.java:22)
>         at TestAutomation.main(TestAutomation.java:28)

Comment: You can add Appium Server log also, It will easy to find out the problem

Comment: I tried to get server logs, but pretty much nothing there on the logs, because connection is not made to the Server at all.

Comment: Forgot to add my Appium Server version is 1.9.1

Comment: Is your appium server running?

Comment: Yes, verified with `netstat -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have problem with the desired capabilities.

> **appActivity** and **appPackage** must be included.
>
> **device** from your desired capabilities must be removed.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "your app Package");
caps.setCapability("appActivity",
            "your app activity");;
```

> Also update your selenium-java version to latest stable version.

Comment: Tried with that doesn't work - Also, getting `nullPointerException`. If the error was related to session creation or something may be that would make some difference. Likely some compatibility issue?

Comment: Which selenium-java version are you using? I am using 3.13.0 and its working fine for me.

Comment: I think your problem is related to the selenium-java version. Try cahnaging it to 3.13.0 version.

Comment: Sure Let me try that.

Comment: Yes that works - with latest selenium version 3.141.59. Thanks. Will mark this as answer. Can you please update the answer that says - "Please Try updating the Selenium version to latest and try" I will then mark this as answer

Comment: i have update the answer to "update selenium-java version to latest stable version"